# JOOQ select expression

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jooq

I am trying to construct a select/groupby query on a postgres table `TABLE` with a JSON column `TAGS` in JOOQ:

```
val select = arrayOf(DSL.field("{0}->>{1}", String::class.java, TABLE.TAGS, DSL.inline(fields[0])),
  DSL.sum(TABLE.VALUE))
val groupBy = arrayOf(DSL.field("{0}->>{1}", String::class.java, TABLE.TAGS, DSL.inline(fields[0]))
dsl()
  .select(select)
  .from(TABLE)
  .groupBy(groupBy)
  .fetch()
```

I'm getting errors saying that `select()` expects `Array<SelectField<?>>` but my expression is of type `Array<Field<out Any!>!>`.

Comment: Looks like a Kotlin compiler type inference problem, at least when working with Java interoperability. Have you reported this to Jetbrains? Java arrays are covariant, it seems that Kotlin arrays are not.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the select expression from using Array to using separate arguments and the error went away. Reported to Jetbrains as well.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you found a workaround. Feel free to also answer your own question here on Stack Overflow. I'm sure someone might find that answer useful, in the future!